# form edit modal ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

i have problem with form edit modal ajax,edit form can pop up but data still empty.code like this,
my controller:

```html
public function edit()
 {
  $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
  
  
  $data=array(
  'project' => $this->m_inputactivity->get_project(),
  'actype' => $this->m_inputactivity->get_actype(),
  'detail' => $this->m_inputactivity->per_id($id),
  '
  );
  
  
  $this->output
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode($data));
 }
```

my view:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit(id)
{
   
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('input_activity/edit/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

           
   
            $("[name='actype']").val(data.actype);
            $("[name='activity_name']").val(data.activity_name);
   $("[name='project']").val(data.project);
            $("[name='portion']").val(data.portion);
            $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
}

function reload_table()
{
    table.ajax.reload(null,false); //reload datatable ajax 
}
</script>
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit('<?php echo $row->activity_detail_id;?>')"  class="btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm purple" >
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </a>
```

my modal view:

```html
<!-- begin pop update activity -->
<div class="modal fade left" id="modal_form"> 
<div class="modal-dialog"> 
<div class="modal-content"> 
<div class="modal-header"> 
<h3 class="pull-left no-margin">Edit Activity</h3>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button> 
</div> 
<div class="modal-body">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>input_activity/update"> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Kategori:</label> 
<div class="col-sm-9"> 
<?php $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "actype"';
echo form_dropdown('actype',$actype,set_value('actype',$detail[0]->activity_type),$attributes);?>
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="activity" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Rincian Kegiatan: </label> 
<div class="col-sm-9"> 
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="activity_name"  required><?php echo $detail[0]->activity_name;?></textarea>
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="project" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Peruntukkan:</label> 
<div class="col-sm-9"> 
<?php $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "project"'; 
echo form_dropdown('project',$project,set_value('project',$detail[0]->project_id),$attributes);?>
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="portion" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bobot:</label> 
<div class="col-sm-4"> 
<input class="form-control" name="portion" value="<?php echo $detail[0]->portion;?>" required>
<input name="activity_detail_id" type="hidden" id="activity_detail_id" value="<?php echo $detail[0]->activity_detail_id;?>">
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">
<button type="submit" class="btn green">
<i class="fa fa-save"></i> Update</button>
<button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div> 
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

i have problem when i click edit button popup data still empty

[image]

how to create modal ajax correctly?

Comment: have you checked that you are actually getting the data you expect back from the ajax call? e.g. `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` would allow you to check that the format of the returned data matches up. And also check the console for any errors, e.g. network errors. Second thing obviously is to ensure that the names of the form fields you're referring to when populating the modal are definitely correct.

Comment: where i can put console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: after `success: function(data)
        {` - you want to examine the `data` variable after it's returned from the server. Have your browser console (F12) open when you run the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the controller is actually returning the correct data the problem might be the selectors for the form inputs.

Try these selectors to set the values.

```
$("input[name='actype']").val(data.actype);
$("input[name='activity_name']").val(data.activity_name);
$("input[name='project']").val(data.project);
$("input[name='portion']").val(data.portion);
```

You don't show the view html. But it is assumed that the modal html is in the same file that contains the javascript you show. True?